# How to use key-value object as datasource for Angular Material table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have an API response that looks like this:

```
{
  "2019-02-13": {
    "costs": 117,
    "commission": 271.07
  },
  "2019-02-14": {
    "costs": 123,
    "commission": 160.37
  },
  //etc..
}
```

I want to use this object as a datasource for my material data table, but I get this error:

> Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

I tried using a cell definition like this:

```
//cost
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item | keyvalue"> {{item.value.costs}} </td>
//date
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item | keyvalue"> {{item.key}} </td>
```

But that didn't work.

I could of course loop through my object and make an array like this:

```
[
  {
    commission: 100,
    costs: 45
    date: '2019-02-13'
  },
  {
    commission: 100,
    costs: 45
    date: '2019-02-13'
  }
]
```

This will probably fix my problem, but I'd rather not do this because I feel like it's unnecessary.

**Edit**

I fixed it with adding this code to my service call:

```
let data = [];
for (let key in response) {
  let value = response[key];
  let obj = {date: key, commission: value.commission, costs: value.costs}
  data.push(obj);
}
return data;
```

Comment: In my opinion, do what you just said at the end and that is a very good programming practice. And if your data is coming from an API then it is going to be much easier to turn them into objects during your service call.

Comment: If you fixed your problem, you can add it below as an "Answer" and accept it.

Comment: I did fixed my problem, but I'm still looking for a better fix tbh.

Answer (score 1):

If you would have two interfaces:

```
interface Foo {
  [key:string]: myDataContent[];
}
interface myDataContent{
  costs: number;
  commission: number;
}
```

and a service call which returns you `Foo[]` into a list, e.g. `lstValues` and the rest should be easy. The key you could get from the `Object.keys`